# How do display the pdf file in scala template page in play 2 framework?

Tags: java, html, pdf, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have successfully generated the pdf using some 3rd party library,but now i am stuck at the point as to how to display the generated pdf file in the browser using scala template. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to use a built-in controller method for serving files.

**Java solution**:

```
File file = getYourPdfFile();
return ok(file);
```

The *ok* method is overloaded and accepts a file, a stream or a byte array. The Java documentation can be found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaStream).

**Scala solution**:

```
def serveFile(file: File, fileName: String) {
  Ok.sendFile(
    content = file,
    fileName = _ => fileName
  )
}
```

If you want to have more control over a response you can build it manually. Hereunder you have an example which uses a byte array as a response body:

```
def byteArrayToResult(pdfAsByteArray: Array[Byte], fileName: String): Result = {
  val ticketInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAsByteArray)
  val fileContent = Enumerator.fromStream(ticketInputStream)
  val headers = Map(
    CONTENT_LENGTH -> pdfAsByteArray.length.toString,
    CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=$fileName"
  )
  Result(ResponseHeader(200, headers), fileContent
  ).as("application/pdf")
}
```

Depending on the way that you hold a generated file you can also use `Enumerator.fromFile()` instead of the `fromStream()` method. You can read more about a whole concept in the Scala [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaStream).

Comment: Thanks Daniel,but i am using java version of play,how will the code differ if i am writing it in java.And also how do i display the generated pdf file in html page, do i have to add any specific tags to instruct it to open in browser.

Comment: I was misled by the Scala tag in your question. The solution for Java is quite similar. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,i very much followed you,but the ajax call (success event) renders the pdf as some weird characters in the browser window.Do,i need to have a separate html page for it or will it render inline? How do i go after this?.